# Need rdl sorting expression not in abc order

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

My Data:
SLP,PT,OT

Currently I am doing Z to A order, so it's coming as SLP,PT,OT

I need as SLP,OT,PT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a switch expression..

```
=switch(Fields!Thingy.Value = "SLP", 1, Fields!Thingy.Value = "OT", 2, ..etc)
```

I always end mine with

```
1=1, 9999)
```

so that any not accounted for will go at the end. You can also use

```
TRUE, 9999)
```